# How to check if a button is pressed while running a program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I want to run a program in Python while also checking the **whole** time whether or not a button (the physical type) has been pressed. The program looks something like this:

```
import stuff

a = True

def main():
        important stuff which takes about 10 seconds to complete

while True:
        if a == True:
                main() 
                #at the same time as running main(), I also want to check if a button
                #has been pressed. If so I want to set a to False
```

I can check if the button has been pressed after main is completed, but that would mean I would have to press the button at the split second when python checks if the button has been pressed (or hold down the button).

How can I make python check whether the button has been pressed **while** main() is running?

Comment: [Create another thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) that only watches for whether the button has been pressed. When the button is pressed, have it set a flag that the 'main' thread is looking at when it determines whether to re-run `main()` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can try. The `main` function is printing a number every second, and you can interrupt it by typing "s" + the Enter key :

```
import threading
import time

a = True

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        if a:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i) 

def interrupt():
    global a # otherwise you can only read, and not modify "a" value globally
    if input("You can type 's' to stop :") == "s":
        print("interrupt !")
        a = False


t1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
t1.start()
interrupt()
```

Comment: The suggestion doesn't seem to work (apart from the fact that '(target=main)' should really be '(target=main()) - in the second to last line). The interrupt() function is only called after main() has finished

Comment: I added a message in the `input` : "You can type 's' to stop :" . In this way you can see that `interrupt` function is called at same time as `main` is starting.
And do not replace `target=main` by `target=main()` or it will not work as a thread...

Comment: The 'You can type 's' to stop' message only appears after all the numbers (0-9) appear

Comment: Additionally when running the actual program the following error appears: File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 781, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Comment: maybe you need to install the lib `pip install threading`